# How to uninstall Spotify

Tags: apt

i have a big error warning in my Ubuntu 14 because of Spotify.

This the error :

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

I want to uninstall this program, how to do it ?

Comment: Spotify seems to have fixed the cause of that error message. No reason any longer to make any changes. (There was never a reason to uninstall the program.)

Answer (score 26):

Use this command for uninstall spotify-client :

```
sudo apt-get purge spotify-client
```

Comment: not working :  Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: First remove the merge list : sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

Comment: Next : sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 9):

This won't be solved by uninstalling Spotify, only by removing the Spotify apt repository from your list of apt repositories.

Editing /etc/apt/sources.list or possibly some file in /etc/apt/source.list.d/ like fhuertas suggests will work.

If you don't want to edit files, you can start Software & Updates, go to the tab Other Software and uncheck `http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`

This is both a problem with the Spotify repository and apt itself.

- The repository is clearly broken. If you look at the file mentioned being broken, you see it contains HTML.
- It is bad of apt to die like this, preventing even critical security upgrades from installing, because of a bad third party repository is broken.

I work at Spotify. We suck! We will fix.

Comment: I'll be waiting here. No pressure aha

Comment: See this answer for more info http://askubuntu.com/a/491607/4865

Answer (score 1):

These terminal commands should solve your problem:

First remove the Merge List by opening a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch) and run this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Next, generate a new one by running a simple update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you should be able to run

`sudo apt-get remove --purge spotify-client`

Comment: sorry not working

Comment: Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
hardov@hardov-VPCY216FX:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge spotify-client
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists after [Charles Green](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491476/how-to-uninstall-spotify/491493#491493)'s solution, You must remove the repository from the places that you have set it.

Im my case, I had the repository en the file: /etc/apt/sources.list and I have removed it adding the `#` in the line symbol before the line `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`

```
 # deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

The repository can be in the /etc/apt/source.list.d/ directory, you must search for a spotify file and remove it

After then update and upgrade the with apt-get tools

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found the solution at the Spotify [forum](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-0-9-11-for-GNU-Linux/td-p/842969/page/4). Credits to `webrunner1981`.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to software sources (search `software & updates`) and find the spotify line
2. Modify the url to `http://repository-origin.spotify.com stable non-free` for `(source code)` as well. Add the `-origin` in the url.
3. In terminal then run the following commands:

   > sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

   and now you can perform the update and everything should be working.

   > sudo apt-get update

This should fix everything, so you don't have to uninstall. Good luck.

Comment: the problem is that ubuntu dont allow me to open Softwares and Updates !

Comment: thnx that fixed the issue for me!