# "Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com" while updating the list

Tags: apt

Everything was working fine just yesterday. Today I wanted to update and it failed with the following error:

```
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Fout!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en
E: De pakketlijsten of het statusbestand konden of niet ontleed, of niet geopend worden.
```

I got Dutch localisation, so I'll try to transate here.. (hopefully it makes sense..)

- first line: Reading package list... error!
- Last line: The packagelist or the status file couldn't be parsed or opened.

Does someone know what happened and how I can correct this issue?

Comment: There were problems with the Spotify repository yesterday. They were apparently reorganizing the repository server. People who tried to install Spotify have noticed various errors. Perhaps try again in a little while.

Comment: In fact, the Merge List is actually a web page that asks me to agree with their Cookie policy. Spotify has really messed things up.

Comment: Hm, I guess so. I tried to use the fix suggested in that other question but that didn't work initially. So I ended up disabling the Spotify repository and tried that solution again and this time it did work! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Haha, They dump a full HTML page in there, no wonder it couldn't be parsed :')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spotify has pushed a new version update and broke the repository.

http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-0-9-11-for-GNU-Linux/td-p/842969

Please disable the spotify repository and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this works then the problem you have is the repository.

Add the following repository instead.

```
deb http://repository-origin.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Check link above for further details and updates.

Answer (score 8):

This won't be solved by uninstalling Spotify, only by removing the Spotify apt repository from your list of apt repositories.

Start the program Software & Updates, go to the tab Other Software and uncheck `http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`

This is both a problem with the Spotify repository and apt itself.

- The repository is clearly broken. If you look at the file mentioned being broken, you see it contains HTML.
- It is bad of apt to die like this, preventing even critical security upgrades from installing, because of a bad third party repository is broken.

I work at Spotify. We suck! We will fix.

Update: You can also wait and the problem will go away once this has been fixed. However, if you badly need to upgrade or install some software right now, you need to remove the repository. If you still want Spotify updates later, don't forget to add it back again.

Update 2: It seems I was incorrect. The repository has been fixed and no longer redirects and returns HTML, but the offending file still needs to be removed, before your can continue.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
```

Comment: Tja! Thanks for your answer. Is this something which will go away automatically once you've fixed it, or do I have to remove and then add it back later when it starts working again?

Comment: This should go away automatically once it is fixed.

Comment: I was incorrect. It fill not go away automatically. You actually need to remove the broken Packages file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wondering, some people suggest to use  http://repository-origin.spotify.com. Is this a good option or is it better to stick with the normal repository?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is similar to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491476/how-to-uninstall-spotify). My answer is the same:

I had the same issue and I found the solution at the Spotify [forum](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-0-9-11-for-GNU-Linux/td-p/842969/page/4). Credits to `webrunner1981`.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to software sources (search `software & updates`) and find the spotify line
2. Modify the url to `http://repository-origin.spotify.com stable non-free` for `(source code)` as well. Add the `-origin` in the url.
3. In terminal then run the following commands:

   > sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

   and now you can perform the update and everything should be working.

   > sudo apt-get update

This should fix everything, so you don't have to uninstall. Good luck.